# Create document by Rest API

Tags: rest, curl, couchbase

I´m trying to create a document `productsId` on couchbase with some contain using the Rest API.

After read the documentation I end up creating this crul script, but I´m not being able to make it works

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d 
'{"country":"France","iata":"A5","callsign":"AIRLINAIR","name":"Airlin Air","icao":"RLA","type":"airline","id": "19810"}' 
Administrator:password@localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/default/docs/productsId
```

I´m receiving a `405. Method Not Allowed`

But in the documentation seems like it´s an option available.

EDIT

The reason why I want to use just the Rest API it's because I need to modify some documents and clean up others in my test framework. Implement the whole API was a little bit overkill. Which surprise me is, that you can create clusters, buckets, delete documents with the Rest API, but not create it?. That sounds very wrong to me.
Regards

Comment: in this case, just use whatever API accessible for your test framework

Comment: But we´re not  exposing the access from the test framework code, because the design does not require it, and one rule of thumb is, never adapt your source code because your test framework needs.

Comment: the API you are trying to use is also not exposed to be used by application. You are trying adapt API which are not public

Comment: But why you can delete documents but not create it?. To me is more dangerous expose the DELETE in the API more than the PUT. Anyway does not has any sense....

Comment: you can create and delete SDKs. to me it is dangerous to rely on the volatile private APIs

Comment: I know I can, I have implement the whole API using SDK in my source code. But again, I dont want to expose that persistent layer in my project because my test framework need to use it, that is wrong, very wrong

Comment: Sorry, but using this API to manage the docs is wrong. You could corrupt the data without noticing it

Comment: I understand, but It´s just for my test, I need to create a document, and then remove it. Just that, I´m not using the API to manage the docs of my application for sure.  Anyway I found that using sync_gateway it´s possible. https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/338 seems promising. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 2):

You should rather write your own backend and expose it through REST. The API you are referencing is not supposed to be used by application.

Read more about it at http://blog.couchbase.com/firstapp-couchbase-nodejs-ottoman

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Couchbase SDK to write documents to Couchbase.

What language is your application written in?

Here is the Java SDK docs for example: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/java/start-using-sdk.html